# Convert input string to number and sum it up

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have the following code, it takes user input string value, assigns alphabetic characters with specific numbers and later on sums them up. Problem is that my code won't work, I wonder where did I make mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addalldata() {

a = j = s = 1;
b = k = t = 2;
c = l = u = 3;
d = m = v = 4;
e = n = w = 5;
f = o = x = 6;
g = p = y = 7;
h = q = z = 8;
i = r = 9;

let userinputname = document.getElementById("fullusernameinput").value;
let userinputnamelow = userinputname.toLowerCase();
let userinputnamearray = userinputnamelow.split('');
let pirvelijami1 = userinputnamearray.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);


alert(pirvelijami1);

}

</script>
```

It returns NaN

Comment: Use an object instead of individual variable names, then use bracket notation to look up the right property on the object inside the `reduce` callback

Comment: ```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addalldata() {

const ricxvebidaasoebi = {
a: 1,
j: 1,
s: 1,
b: 2,
k: 2,
t: 2,
c: 3,
l: 3,
u: 3,
d: 4,
m: 4,
v: 4,
e: 5,
n: 5,
w: 5,
f: 6,
o: 6,
x: 6,
g: 7,
p: 7,
y: 7,
h: 8,
q: 8,
z: 8,
i: 9,
r: 9
}

let userinputname = document.getElementById("fullusernameinput").value;
let userinputnamelow = userinputname.toLowerCase();

let jamijami = Object.userinputnamelow(ricxvebidaasoebi).reduce((t, n) => t + n);


alert(jamijami);

}

</script>
```
Followed your advice, I still somehow get error

Comment: `.reduce((a, char) => a + ricxvebidaasoebi[char], 0)` Bracket notation. Also consider using sensible variable names